# When i browse an Html page inside SharePoint web application throw error

Tags: 2016, iis, 2019

Hi I created SharePoint web application and added a new Virtual directory and converted to application in IIS, i just added an HTML file when I try to browse this html file i get below error

Exception information:  Exception type: EntryPointNotFoundException    Exception message: The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
 - For the app startup parameter value 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Owin.Hosting.Startup, Microsoft.SharePoint.Owin.Hosting, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c', the assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Owin.Hosting, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' was not found.

Comment: This should be tag 2019, because I didn't see that setting in 2016 edition web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you done it on one FE but you are hitting another FE in browser?

Not sure what your requirements but try this instead:. If you want HTML page to display in Sharepoint crate pages library on a site collection, rename your page to aspx and upload it to that library, now you can browse to it.